# Copy, Paste and Rename Inside Browse Dialog

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, files

How can i have Copy, Paste and Rename inside Browse Dialog. I mean inside open or save  dialog.

[image: Save Dialog]

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: Would you mind converting that into an actual answer?

Comment: @David Foerster - I'm not sure if I can convert that into a proper answer. IMO the answer should include some reasons and I can only speculate that's by design. Could it be *hacked* and changed as the OP wants? I don't really know.

Comment: @CelticWarrior: I don't think there needs to be a reason beyond "the developers didn't think that would be an important enough feature so they didn't implement it; they want you to use your favourite file manager for that instead".

Comment: @CelticWarrior: …and that's not speculation. Obviously the feature is technically trivial, so the only other possible reason for its absence is wilful negligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How can i have Copy, Paste and Rename inside Browse Dialog?*

You can't.

The software has been designed that way. It's a developers' decision arguably to avoid mistakes and to steer users towards better practices like using a dedicated file manager for such actions.

Comment: I think Windows has it since 8. It's very nice feature. When i'm using bitwig and want to duplicate a file, i could hit open and go to the folder, select file, copy, paste and finally rename it to the name i want. I think it can not make problem. since Windows done that before. and what can go wrong? you open a file that doesn't paste yet? it can just show file can't be open. For rename i think it can't hurt anything.

Comment: Actually there are lots of potential problems and one actual immediate problem is teaching bad habits. BTW, Windows always had it.